# How to save markup thats been added using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a form where a user can create a CV , the user has the option of 2 to 4 references , 2 being already there. Then a add function to add 2 more if they want.
But when I refresh the page the markup is lost. 
My question is how can I save the markup? 
To a database? any thing Iv looked to saving to a database is mainly for tables.

My markup and script below

```
    <h5><strong>PREVIOUS EMPLOY</strong></h5>

    <hr /><div class="references-container">
           <div class="references">
              <a class="addform">Add</a>
          </div>

          <div class="reference-forms">
          </div>
          </div>

                <script>
                    $(".addform").on("click", function () {
                        let markup = `<div class="addReferenceForm">`;
                        markup += `<ul class="list-details">`;
                        markup += `<li><span class="main-color"> Last employer name:</span><input class="editable" /></li>`;
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">Position:</span><input class="editable" /></li>';
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">License Code:</span><input class="editable" /></li>';
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">Start Date:</span><input class="editable" /></li>';
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">End Date:</span><input class="editable" /></li>';
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">Total Years:</span><input class="editable" /></li>';
                        markup += '<li><span class="main-color">Reason for leaving / or wanting        to leave:</span><br /><input class="editable" /></li></ul>';
    markup += `</div>`;

    $(".reference-forms").append(markup);
          });

    var numItems = $('.addReferenceForm').length;
    alert(numItems);
    </script>

    <ul class="list-details">
          <li>
               <!--Euphoria Software-->
               <span class="main-color">Last employer name:</span>
               <input runat="server" class="editable" />
          </li>

          <li>
               <!-- Website Developer-->
               <span class="main-color">Position:</span> 
               <input runat="server" class="editable" />
         </li>

         <li>
              <!--Code 12, PDP-->
              <span class="main-color">License Code:</span>  
              <input runat="server" class="editable" />
         </li>

         <li>
              <!-- 12 October,2004-->
              <span class="main-color">Start Date:</span> 
              <input runat="server" class="editable" />
        </li>

        <li>
             <!--14 July, 2014 -->
             <span class="main-color">End Date:</span> 
             <input runat="server" class="editable" />
       </li>

       <li>
            <!--10 years-->
            <span class="main-color">Total Years:</span> 
            <input runat="server" class="editable" />
      </li>

      <li>
           <span class="main-color">Reason for leaving / or wanting to leave:       </span>
           <br />
           <input runat="server" class="editable" />
      </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Is the whole form not reset also? I mean when you refresh any form you lose everything you have entered anyway so why bother remembering some values/settings? If you really want to save then yes you would have to save everything, including the data being input in form, to database. Which you will be doing anyway upon form submission, right? Alternative would be to store the markup in local storage. Then remember to clear it on form submission otherwise whenever user returns to the page they will see the extra markup.

Comment: Do you have a specific user id at the time the person is entering this?  If so, I would write some ajax calls to update a database on every keystroke, or maybe every 5 seconds if something has changed.  Playing around with session or local storage is a temporary measure.  Think of a person who is filling this out on one computer (at their crappy job!) then finishing it at home.

Comment: maybe look into local storage if it's been entered on the screen but not yet saved to DB?

Comment: @LarryBud - Not currently. was looking a for a temporary solution as im just front end dev , a temporary solution would allow the back end dev to see what its should look like then add it to the db

Comment: @NawkedKhan was looking for something temporary to mimic the functionality so when the back end dev does the logic it makes sense

Comment: @Nikki9696 , I might just have to do that